# how can I force chrome browser to always accept the request of a notification permission?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, notifications

I am having some difficulties with having chrome letting me request notification permission multiple times.

As you know, to make sure the user will receive the notifications my website will be prompting on screen, the browser must allow the notifications.

What I do is this :

```js
Notification.requestPermission()
```

most of the times it works, and I see a dialog box proposing the user either to allow, or to block notifications.

But, if I dismiss this dialog box more than three times, then Chrome temporarily blocks the request permission for a week! (https://chromestatus.com/feature/6443143280984064)

Does anyone know anyway to bypass this ?

Comment: Hopefully not because there is a reason chrome blocks this: to prevent you from spamming / annoying the user.

Comment: Doubt there's a way, if there was then it would be a security issue. It would allow random websites to give users notification s that are probably misleading and or lead to bad links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer, you cant. It would be a security risk.